# How come cache blocking is slower?

Tags: c++, caching, optimization

I am learning optimizing performance with cache blocking. I am going through examples showing in:
http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~sandhya/csc252/lectures/lecture-memopt.pdf
https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/loop-tiling

I have following code:

**Code1:**

```
for (size_t i=0; i<n; ++i)  {
  for (size_t j=0; j<n; ++j) {
    sum = 0;
    for (size_t k=0; k<n; ++k){
        sum += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
    }
    c[i][j] = sum;
  }
}
```

**Code2** (block size around 50)

```
for(size_t jj=0;jj<n;jj+=jbsize){
    for(size_t kk=0;kk<n;kk+=kbsize){
        for(size_t i=0;i<n;i++){
            for(size_t j=jj;j<std::min((int)jj+jbsize,n);j++){
                sum = 0;
                for(size_t k=kk;k<std::min((int)kk+kbsize,n);k++){
                    sum += a[i][k]*b[k][j];
                }
                c[i][j] += sum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However **Code2** (18s) example is running slower than **Code1** (12s) when I use n=1600. This is opposite to what is stated in the above learning documents. (corrected the time is in sec not in ms)

I also tried the **tiling example** from wiki: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_nest_optimization

This works pretty well when I picked a large ibsize and kbsize and gives performance close around 8ms:

```
for(size_t ii=0;ii<n;ii+=ibsize){
    for(size_t kk=0;kk<n;kk+=kbsize){
        for(size_t j=0;j<n;j+=2){
            for(size_t i=ii;i<std::min((int)ii+ibsize,n);i+=2){
                if(kk==0)
                {
                    acc00 =0; acc01 =0; acc10 =0; acc11 =0;
                }
                else
                {
                    acc00 = c[i + 0][j + 0];
                    acc01 = c[i + 0][j + 1];
                    acc10 = c[i + 1][j + 0];
                    acc11 = c[i + 1][j + 1];
                }
                for(size_t k=kk;k<std::min((int)kk+kbsize,n);k++){
                    acc00 += b[k][j + 0] * a[i + 0][k];
                    acc01 += b[k][j + 1] * a[i + 0][k];
                    acc10 += b[k][j + 0] * a[i + 1][k];
                    acc11 += b[k][j + 1] * a[i + 1][k];
                }
                c[i + 0][j + 0] = acc00;
                c[i + 0][j + 1] = acc01;
                c[i + 1][j + 0] = acc10;
                c[i + 1][j + 1] = acc11;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is why Code2 is not doing so well? Am I doing something wrong here or my choice of n is just not big enough to see the performance improvement? I am running on a PC with Intel i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz.

Note:
I also used "perf" to measure cache-references and cache-misses. Code1 uses a lot more cache references and less % of cache-misses than Code2. The tiling example uses similar cache references to Code2 but is able to give better performance than Code1 (I think it's probably due to a better usage of register. Even though it uses less cache-references but the tiling example has less cache misses overall).

Comment: Don't optimize by hand, if relevant, your compiler will do so

Comment: @JVApen but then does that mean the blocking example is no longer valid? The tiling example from the wiki page definitely improve the performance a lot though.

Comment: Do you build with optimizations enabled? Have you looked at the generated assembly code? Calling functions in loop conditions is not a good idea if you want to micro-optimize. Also, optimization involving caches depends a lot on the caches themselves, their sizes, and more.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I just want to find out why is the blocking tutorial example is not actually working under the same condition. Because if this is not working, then the fundamental concept stated in the learning document is no longer correct? The tiling example definitely works better?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude btw, optimization flag is enabled I believe

Comment: @JVApen a compiler is not a magic wand.

Comment: @harold it ain't, however, it is powerful. For 99% of the cases, trust it

Comment: @JVApen trust that the compiler has an extremely rare research-level optimization? Maybe if OP is using IBM XL

Comment: @harold: Page is from 2007, so ain't rare any more. And most optimizations nowadays even directly get implemented in LLVM for testing purpose, upstream time doesn't take that long if relevant

Comment: @JVApen it is an extremely old technique that is rarely implemented. In LLVM does have Polly but it's a kind of separate thing.

Comment: @JVApen if you believe the compiler can just optimize the code directly, can you run the above code with the ijk, jik nested loop and the tiling example. Do you actually get similar results on all of them? Mine has very clear difference in performance when n is quite large.

Comment: @JohnYang: depends on the compiler (as already indicated, including Polly) and the CPU, cause prefetching might compensate a lot! I'm not saying you shouldn't do this, though it shouldn't be your default as developers are really bad at optimizing code

Comment: @JVApen but this doesn't answer my question. The example I am showing is just a simple nested loop which people are using for teaching at school. If the teaching material for some fundamental computer science is not giving out the right results, there has to be a reason. If it is the compiler or CPU is giving me the bad results, I want to know the exact reason. And it's not a complicated example?

Comment: OK so I could not explain this, but I did notice an other odd thing: the times shouldn't have been 12ms and 16ms for n=1600 - that implies an implausible FLOPS rate.

Comment: @harold yes you are right. I made a mistake, it's in seconds not ms.

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce your results on my (admittedly several years old) system. For N=1600, Code1 takes 44s and Code2 (block size = 50x50) takes 5.8s.

Comment: Make sure that `jbsize` and `kbsize` are declared as compile-time constants to help the compiler with unrolling the inner loops.

Comment: @andars interesting. you can actually get much faster time for Code2 than Code1. Good suggestion for the compile time constants, which actually makes it faster slightly. But my code1 and code 2 are still both running at around 12~16s. What machine are you using and is it Windows or Linux?

Comment: OS X 10.11, but I wouldn't expect OS to matter much here. CPU is i5-2435M @ 2.40GHz. I'll try on a newer CPU a bit later and see what it looks like there.

Comment: have you tried code3? does it make it even faster on your machine? I just figured out that the std::min function is actually making it slow. So my code 2 can run faster than code1. And also disabling the optimization, my code1 is actually much slower too.

Comment: Also I noticed now I have to use n = 1800 or more to start seeing code2 running significantly faster than jik loop or code1

Comment: I was doing everything as separate unit test with gtest, so I just found out the behaviour is actually quite different when I just recreate an executable separately. Now I'm getting 3.3s code1, 2.4s code2 and 1.4s code3.